# Check the presence of a value in two diff enums using diff logic

Tags: c#, enums

I have two different enums where each has a set of values. Eg:

```
public enum TeamsUserPolicyType
    {
        OnlineDialinConferencingPolicy,

        OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy,

        TeamsAppPermissionPolicy, //Called as AppsPermission in UserAssignedSettingType

        TeamsAppSetupPolicy
    }

    public enum UserAssignedSettingType
    {
        Meeting,

        MeetingBranding,

        AppsSetup,

        AppsPermission,//Called as TeamsAppPermissionPolicyin TeamsUserPolicyType

        EventsPolicy,

        TeamsRoomVideoTeleConferencingPolicy
    }
```

now, I have a method that takes an enum, checks if TeamsAppPermission Policy is present in it or not. something like below

```
private bool HasTeamsAppPermissionPolicy(IList<UserAssignedSettingType> userPolicyTypes)
        {
            var hasuserAppPermPolicy = userPolicyTypes.Contains(UserAssignedSettingType.AppsPermission);
            return hasuserAppPermPolicy;
        }
```

here, I want this method to operate for both enum types. i.e if `UserAssignedSettingType` is passed in `userPolicyTypes` variable, I need to execute above logic. if `TeamsUserPolicyType` is passed in, I need to check for `TeamsAppPermissionPolicy` instead of `AppsPermission` as thats the corresponding type in `TeamsUserPolicyType` enum. I can easily solve this by declaring another overloaded method as `private bool HasTeamsAppPermissionPolicy(IList<TeamsUserPolicyType> userPolicyTypes)` but want to know if there is a better way using generics.

Comment: *"want to know if there is a better way"*. There isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that I guess:

```
    public static bool HasPolicy<TEnum>(this IEnumerable<TEnum> availablePolicies, TEnum policyToCheck) where TEnum : struct
    {
        return availablePolicies.Contains(policyToCheck);
    }
```

then use it:

```
if (userPolicyTypes.HasPolicy(UserAssignedSettingType.AppsPermission))
...
```